# Using OAuth to authenticate Office 365/Graph users with Django

Tags: python, django, oauth, microsoft-graph-api

We are creating an application for use in our organization, but we only want people in our organization to be able to use the app. We had the idea of using Microsoft's OAuth endpoint in order to authenticate whether a user is part of our org or not. The idea is to bring up a sign in screen where the user can enter their Office 365 username and password, which will then allow them to use our app upon submission of their credentials.

Our app is running on Django, and I've only found a solution to this problem using Flask and [Microsoft's Graph API connect sample for Python](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/python3-connect-rest-sample) (See code snippet below). This sample uses a similar idea to the one above to log in to the app. Are there any similar methods of authentication for Django?

```
import requests
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, session, request, render_template
from flask_oauthlib.client import OAuth

# read private credentials from text file
client_id, client_secret, *_ = open('_PRIVATE.txt').read().split('\n')
if (client_id.startswith('*') and client_id.endswith('*')) or \
    (client_secret.startswith('*') and client_secret.endswith('*')):
    print('MISSING CONFIGURATION: the _PRIVATE.txt file needs to be edited ' + \
        'to add client ID and secret.')
    sys.exit(1)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.secret_key = 'development'
oauth = OAuth(app)

# since this sample runs locally without HTTPS, disable InsecureRequestWarning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()

msgraphapi = oauth.remote_app( \
    'microsoft',
    consumer_key=client_id,
    consumer_secret=client_secret,
    request_token_params={'scope': 'User.Read Mail.Send'},
    base_url='https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/',
    request_token_url=None,
    access_token_method='POST',
    access_token_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token',
    authorize_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize'
                             )

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    """Handler for login route."""
    guid = uuid.uuid4() # guid used to only accept initiated logins
    session['state'] = guid
    return msgraphapi.authorize(callback=url_for('authorized', _external=True), state=guid)

@app.route('/login/authorized')
def authorized():
    """Handler for login/authorized route."""
    response = msgraphapi.authorized_response()

    if response is None:
        return "Access Denied: Reason={0}\nError={1}".format( \
            request.args['error'], request.args['error_description'])

    # Check response for state
    if str(session['state']) != str(request.args['state']):
        raise Exception('State has been messed with, end authentication')
    session['state'] = '' # reset session state to prevent re-use

    # Okay to store this in a local variable, encrypt if it's going to client
    # machine or database. Treat as a password.
    session['microsoft_token'] = (response['access_token'], '')
    # Store the token in another session variable for easy access
    session['access_token'] = response['access_token']
    me_response = msgraphapi.get('me')
    me_data = json.loads(json.dumps(me_response.data))
    username = me_data['displayName']
    email_address = me_data['userPrincipalName']
    session['alias'] = username
    session['userEmailAddress'] = email_address
    return redirect('main')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use just about any OAUTH 2.0 library for Python. I've not worked with Django but I know there are several out there for Python.

I came across [django-azure-ad-auth](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/) which seems to be exactly what you're looking for.

I also found a general OAUTH library called [django-allauth](https://www.intenct.nl/projects/django-allauth/) which seems to have a lot of activity. It doesn't have a built-in provider but the model they use for providers seems simple enough that you may be able to extend it without too much trouble.