# Office 365 with allauth

Tags: azure-active-directory, django-allauth

I posed this [question earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45289949/using-oauth-to-authenticate-office-365-graph-users-with-django). The best solution seems to be django-allauth, but Office 365 unfortunately isn't in the providers list.

Is there a way to implement Office 365 with django-allauth?

> We are creating an application for use in our organization, but we
>   only want people in our organization to be able to use the app. We had
>   the idea of using Microsoft's OAuth endpoint in order to authenticate
>   whether a user is part of our org or not. The idea is to bring up a
>   sign in screen where the user can enter their Office 365 username and
>   password, which will then allow them to use our app upon submission of
>   their credentials. Our app is running on Django, and I've only found a
>   solution to this problem using Flask and Microsoft's Graph API connect
>   sample for Python. This sample uses a similar idea to the one above to
>   log in to the app. Could anyone help direct me to where I could find a
>   similar method of authentication for Django?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://github.com/sebastus/azure-python-authenticate? Since you don't want users from other organizations, you should just create the app definition in one AD and skip over the multi-tenant parts of the sample.